# If is_page array not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to put different revolution sliders in different pages on my wordpress site, i currently have about 50 pages on the site with a different slider needed for each of them. I have done this with elseif's statements here

```
 <?php 
 if ( is_front_page( )) { 
 putRevSlider( "slider" );
 } elseif (is_page('page-2')) {
 putRevSlider( "slider-2" );  
 } elseif (is_page('page-3')) {
 putRevSlider( "slider-2" );  
 } elseif (is_page('page-4')) {
 putRevSlider( "slider-2" );  
 } else { 
 putRevSlider( "page-slider" );
 }
 ?>
```

I have tried doing this in an array for simplicity reasons and not have loads of elseif statements, but it doesnt show a revolution slider on any page, here's what i have so far

```
 <?php 
 if ( is_front_page( )) { 
 putRevSlider( "slider" );
 } elseif (is_page( array( 'page-1', 'page-2', 'page-3', 'page-4' )) {
 putRevSlider( "slider-1" );  
 } else { 
 putRevSlider( "slider-2" );
 }
 ?>
```

Is there anything am i missing as to why this isn't working?

Comment: `is_page(array('etc..'))` should have worked. What exactly is happening because your question isn't quite clear? maybe you can do into detail on what the expected output is and what is actually currently happening

Comment: @IsThisJavascript basically no sliders appear on any of the pages when i use  is_page(array('etc..'))

Comment: I feel like it may be something to do with the `putRevSlider` function. Could we do a bit low level debugging and see if `is_page` is running correctly? Before every `putRevSlider` place a `die("Reached front page rev slider");` / `die("Reached array page rev slider");` / `die("Reached else page rev slider");` and lets see the results.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript strangely enough i tried this                                    <?php 
if ( is_front_page( )) { 
echo "Reached front page rev slider";
} elseif (is_page( array( 'course', 'overview', 'gallery', 'scorecards' )) {
echo "Reached array page rev slider"; 
} else { 
echo "Reached else page rev slider";
}
?>                                                                                                          And had no echos return on any of the pages

Comment: that is weird because one of those echos must hit. Check view source it's possible it's hidden from display. Sorry I did not reply sooner; I finished work and I didn't check Stackoverflow until this morning

Comment: @IsThisJavascript nothing in the source code, strange issue. giving up with it, it just doesn't seem to want to work when i put the pages in a array. will just use loads of elseif statements to achieve what i want